# Apache Spark: resulting file being created at worker node instead of master node

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, mesos

I configure one master at local pc and a worker node inside virtualbox and the result file has been creating at worker node, instread of sending back to master node, I wonder why is that.

Because my worker node cannot send result back to master node? how to verify that?

I use spark2.2. 
I use same **username** for master and worker node.
I also configured ssh without password.
I tried **--deploy-mode client** and **--deploy-mode cluster**
I tried once then I switched the master/worker node and I got the same result.

```
val result = joined.distinct()
result.write.mode("overwrite").format("csv")
      .option("header", "true").option("delimiter", ";")
      .save("file:///home/data/KPI/KpiDensite.csv")
```

also, for input file, I load like this:

```
val commerce = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true")
  .option("delimiter", "|").load("file:///home/data/equip-serv-commerce-infra-2016.csv").distinct()
```

but why must I presend the file both at master and worker node at the same position? I don't use yarn or mesos right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exporting to a local file system, which tells Spark to write it on the file system of the machine running the code. On the worker, that will be the file system of the worker machine.

If you want the data to be stored on the file system of the driver (not master, you'll need to know where the driver is running on your yarn cluster), then you need to collect the RDD or data frame and use normal IO code to write the data to a file.

The easiest option, however, is to use a distributed storage system, such as HDFS (`.save("hdfs://master:port/data/KPI/KpiDensite.csv")`) or export to a database (writing to a JDBC or using a nosql db); if you're running your application in cluster mode.

Comment: Just to be clear: it's because you're using the `file` scheme, which points to the local file system.

Comment: yes, I understand what you said, the local file system. So now if I add more worker node, the result will be split to all the worker node or there is one worker which finished the last **join** and save the file to it?

Comment: I tried with 2 workers and one worker holds all the resultat. it is time to try hdfs.

Comment: @mingzhao.pro Yes, it depends on the partitions in the backing RDD. If there's only one partition, then only one file will contain the data across the cluster. If you want to have all the data in one file (regardless of storage), then you need to call `coalesce(1)` on your rdd, keeping in mind that a single machine will have to be able to carry all the data in memory.

Comment: what is wierd is the result fold contains 200 small csv files which sum up to only <20MB. why isn't is one file by default, since it is < 64MB? and for **DataSet/DataFrame**, if I transfor to RDD of 2 partition and save, will I have a part of the result on each of my worker machine or not?